# How to configure nginx to accept all subdomain?

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, subdomain

This is part of `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
   listen 80 default deferred; # for Linux
   server_name *.server.com.br;
   client_max_body_size 4G;

   # omitted
}
```

I want to accept **without redirecting**:

```
www.server.com.br
server.com.br
google.server.com.br
facebook.server.com.br
```

How to configure server block?

Comment: downvote for the low hanging fuits (docs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](http://nginx.org/r/server_name) shows how to do this:

```
server_name .server.com.br;
```